Imposing perfect slip boundary conditions in Stokes equations with Nitsche's method
I am working with a 2d mesh, given by a square with a circular hole placed in the middle. Let me call $\partial \Omega$ the boundary at the circle. I have a PDE for a vector field $\vec{v}$, and I want to impose the boundary conditions  (BCs)
$[\hat{n}(\vec{v})] \cdot \vec{v} = 0 \textrm{ on } \partial \Omega$.
Where $\hat{n}(\vec{v})$ is a vector field defined on $\partial \Omega$ which depends on $\vec{v}$.
I looked up in the literature how to construct the Nitsche's functional $F_N$ to add to the PDE's variational functional to implement the BC, in particular "On weakly imposed boundary conditions for second order problems", J. Freund and R. Steinberg, Proceedings of the International Conference on Finite Elements in Fluidds (1995).
Following that reference, I set
$F_N = const. * \frac{\beta}{h} \int_{\partial \Omega} dS \{ [\hat{n}( \vec{v})] \cdot \vec{v}\} \{  [\hat{n}(\vec{v})] \cdot \vec{ \nu}$ },
where $\vec{\nu}$ is the test function associated with $\vec{v}$. When I implement this numericall (I am using Fenics) this does not work: the BC is not satisfied.
Let alone the numerical implementation, may you please tell me what is the general procedure to construct $F_N$ given the BC? Is the $F_N$ above the correct one to implement the perfect-slip BC above?
Thank you !
